# Can you use a different compiler when the first one fails to build a crate?

Tags: rust, compiler-errors, rust-cargo

I am trying to compile a project and I need to use the `reqwest` crate, which is dependent on the `ring` and `mime_guess` crates. When using the MinGW compiler, `ring` fails, but with tdm-gcc, `mime_guess` won't build.

Is it possible to use a fallback compiler? If yes, how?

Comment: reqwest isn't dependent on ring by default, only if you opt to use rustls-tls instead of native-tls.

Comment: How did you install the MinGW compiler?  Have you tried installing rust with rustup-init.exe instead?

Comment: Yes, I used rustup. I don't really remember how I installed it, I did it when I first got this laptop (a year ago)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the tdm-gcc directory renamed, but first in the PATH, so that when you need to build something with it, just name it properly and any programs looking for gcc.exe can find it.